# flash message test fails with react-testing-library / material-ui

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am testing if an error flash message is rendered when login submit fails in 'loginContainer.test.js'. The flash message is a material-ui snackbar component which pops up for a couple of seconds.

Where I am now is 'click submit button event' is successfully fired and 'login action' is failed. I see that the location of history props matches to '/login', not '/' which is a redirected page on login success.

I have tried to get flash message text in a several ways.
1.

```
const getById = queryByAttribute.bind(null, 'id');
const clientMsg = getById(container, 'client-msg');
console.log('clientMsg: ', clientMsg);
```

2. `getByTestId('client-msg');`
3. `getByText('아이디 또는 비밀번호 오류입니다.').toBeInTheDocument();`
4. `getByText('아이디 또는 비밀번호 오류입니다.').toBeVisible();`

   - flash message is a reusable component that is imported in the parents component of all the others, App.js.
     [ file structure ]
     component / auth / loginContainer
     shared / message / snackbarContainer

### loginContainer.test.js

```
const { component, submitButton, usernameInput, passwordInput } = setUp();
  const { container, getByText } = component;

  fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: username } });
  fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: '-1' } });

  fireEvent.click(submitButton);
  await wait(() => {
    expect(mockUserLogin).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  const unlisten = history.listen(expect(location.pathname).toMatch('/login'));
  unlisten();

  getByText('아이디 또는 비밀번호 오류입니다.').toBeInTheDocument();
  getByText('아이디 또는 비밀번호 오류입니다.').toBeVisible();
```

### shared / message / snackbarContentWrapper.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SnackbarContent from '@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
/* --- Components --- */
import Icon from '../../../assets/icons';
import IconButton from '../form/iconButton';

const color = {
  success: '#43A047',
  warning: '#FFA000',
  error: '#ed4337',
  info: '#2196F3',
};

const styles = theme => ({
  success: { backgroundColor: '' },
  error: { backgroundColor: '' },
  info: { backgroundColor: '' },
  warning: { backgroundColor: '' },
  container: {},
  messageBox: {},
  icon: {},
});

const SnackbarContentWrapper = ({ classes, message, variant, onClose }) => {
  const iconColor = color[variant];
  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      id="client-msg"
      className={`${classes[variant]} ${classes.container}`}
      aria-describedby="client-msg"
      message={
        <span id="client-msg" className={classes.messageBox}>
          <div className={classes.icon}>
            <Icon
              name={variant}
              width="20"
              height="20"
              viewBox="0 0 20 20"
              fillOuter="#ffffff"
              fillInner={iconColor}
            />
          </div>
          {message}
        </span>
      }
      action={[
        <IconButton
          name="close"
          width="20"
          height="20"
          viewBox="0 0 20 20"
          type="client-msg"
          handleClick={onClose}
        />,
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

### shared / message / customizedSnackbar

````
import SnackbarContentWrapper from './snackbarContentWrapper';

const CustomizedSnackbar = ({ show, variant, message, removeFlashMessage }) => {
  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    removeFlashMessage();
  };
  return (
    <Snackbar
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'center',
      }}
      open={show}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <SnackbarContentWrapper
        onClose={handleClose}
        variant={variant}
        message={message}
      />
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

## loginContainer.js
```
import LoginForm from './loginForm';
/* --- Actions --- */
import { userLogin } from '../../../actions/authAction';
import { addFlashMessage } from '../../../actions/messageAction';

export const Login = ({
  history,
  // actions
  userLogin,
  addFlashMessage,
}) => {
  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    const { username, password } = values;

    try {
      const token = await userLogin(username, password);
      history.push('/');
    } catch (error) {
      addFlashMessage('error', '아이디 또는 비밀번호 오류입니다.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>Login Form component is here</div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  userLogin: (username, password) => dispatch(userLogin(username, password)),
  addFlashMessage: (variant, message) =>
    dispatch(addFlashMessage(variant, message)),
});
```

I am expecting to have '아이디 또는 비밀번호 오류입니다.' error message text for a couple of seconds when login submit fails.
````

Comment: assume it's because flash messages uses portal inside. check this long thread https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/62 there are at least 3 different workarounds

Comment: Material ui snackbar does not use portal inside.